# issue with nested for loop calculation

Tags: java, for-loop, nested-loops, calculated-columns

So I'm a (major) novice to java and i'm writing a simple program that prints out a table of monthly loan payments. I've got the formatting down but the nested for loop calculation is going over my head. I need to be able to deduct a monthly payment of $50 and figure in an interest rate I've prompted from the user from an initial loan of $1000.

Everything I've tried so far has either resulted in an infinite loop or the very first balance calculation being printed for all 12 months.

This is probably a very obvious question but any feedback would be much appreciated! For loops aren't very intuitive for me, and staring at this same bit of code has halted my progress!

```
( ..... )


//this method prompts the user to enter the annual interest rate and then prints it 
//along with the initial loan, monthly payment, and a simple loan payment table for 
//one year

private static void simpleLoanPaymentTable() {
  Scanner CONSOLE = new Scanner(System.in);
  double annualInterestRate;
  double initialLoan = 1000.0;
  double monthlyPayment = 50.0;

  System.out.println("Please enter the annual interest rate:");
  annualInterestRate = CONSOLE.nextDouble();
  double percentAnnualRate = (annualInterestRate/100);
  double percentMonthlyRate = (percentAnnualRate/12);
  System.out.println();
  System.out.println("The initial loan is $1000.0");
  System.out.println("The monthly payment is $50.0");
  System.out.println("The annual interest rate is " + annualInterestRate + "%");
  System.out.println();


  System.out.println("Simple Loan Payment Table For One Year");
  System.out.println();
  System.out.println(" Month  Balance");


  //create 12 rows for the months
  for(int row = 1; row <= 12; row++) { 
    //calculate monthly balance 
    for(double i = 0; i <= initialLoan; i++) {
      i = (initialLoan-monthlyPayment+(initialLoan*percentMonthlyRate));
      System.out.println(" " + row + "      " + i);
    }
  }
  System.out.println();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you *think* this is doing?

```
for(double i = 0; i <= initialLoan; i++) {
  i = (initialLoan-monthlyPayment+(initialLoan*percentMonthlyRate));
  System.out.println(" " + row + "      " + i);
}
```

What is *actually* going on is that you are assigning the same value to `i` over and over again.

Sit down with a pencil and paper and do the loan calculation by hand.  Then convert the process you went through into code.

Hint: based on what I think you ought to be doing, the inner loop should not be a `for` loop.

Comment: Good advice, I don't know why I thought putting a second for loop would simplify the code when it just ended up overcomplicating it. Putting it on paper and working it as a calculation cleared the confusion. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Do NOT change the loop iterator inside the for loop itself.  It's already being changed every iteration at the top of the loop; what you need to do inside the loops is USE these iterators.

So in your case, you say

```
for(int row = 1; row <= 12; row++) {
```

which means start with row = 1, increase it by 1 every iteration, and go until you are no longer less than or equal to 12.  Then you say

```
for(double i = 0; i <= initialLoan; i++) {
```

which means start with i = 0, increase it by 1 every iteration, and go until you are less than or equal to your initial loan.  Notice that something's not adding up already: your iterator i shouldn't be increasing by 1 until you get to the initial loan, (I believe) it should be iterating by 1 until your calculated loan gets to the initial loan.

Then inside the nexted loops, USE these two iterators (but do not change them) to calculate the loan you are at currently in your row/column.

This will solve your infinite loop problem (unless the math is still incorrect), but still might not be the answer that you're looking for.  Ask yourself, what are your "rows" in this table supposed to represent?  What are the columns in this table supposed to represent? And then figure out how to calculate the number in the table USING (but not changing) the row value (month) and the column value (i) at any given iteration.

EDIT: Again, I might be mishandling the math, but I messed around with it myself and realized that you do not actually have any columns in your table: it's only rows(==months).  So you only need one loop to iterate along the months, and the rest is merely a calculation to figure out.  Check this out and see if this is what you're looking for:

```
double currentLoan = initialLoan;
for(int row = 1; row <= 12; row++) {
    //calculate monthly balance
    currentLoan = (currentLoan-monthlyPayment)*(1+percentMonthlyRate);
    System.out.println(" " + row + "\t" + currentLoan);
}
```

Comment: Ah yes!! That edit helped. I had tried your initial solution and had gotten an infinite loop again even after tinkering with it. I think the second for loop I put in was just superfluous. I'll have to go back through and make sure the math is correct but I definitely agree with your logic. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Glad to hear.  Make sure to mark the topic as closed/accept the answer so that anyone coming to this thread later doesn't try and answer it.  Also, be sure to avoid integer division in your program (annualInterestRate/100, percentAnnualRate/12) -> (annualInterestRate/100.0, percentAnnualRate/12.0) because these are NOT equivalent when you use integers.